# How to use data attribute to assign them to a div container?

Tags: jquery, html, containers, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to get into HTML5 and JS things. By now not quite sucessful.

I want to load some data-attributes from "li" elements dynamically into a div container. The div container will give some additional information to a slide of the flexslider.

HTML:

```
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li data-text="Text 1">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/90x75/00CC00/ffffff" />
        </li>
        <li data-text="Text 2">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/90x75/CD0074/ffffff" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/90x75/FF7400/ffffff" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/90x75/FF0000/ffffff" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The "data-text" element should be printed in the following empty <"span"> of the div by click.
The content of each data-attribute of the list is unique. The slides are thumbnails that act like a navigation:

```
<div class="info-text"> <span></span>
    <a class="votebutton" href="#">Abstimmen</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#carousel ul.slides > li').click(function () {
    $('#carousel ul.slides > li').data('text').add('#info-text > span');
    console.log($('#carousel ul.slides > li').data('text'));
});
```

I know it's lazy to ask for a solution but I'm trying to figure out a solution for three hours. Tried with .add(), .appendTo() and attr.()

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly this maybe the code you're looking for

`$('.info-text > span').text($(this).data('text'));`

*corrected Banners post*

Comment: $('#info-text > span').text($(this).data('text'));

Comment: As i read the question, seems the answer but OP's code is trying to use is really confusing. And yes, use $(this) inside click handler

Comment: Updated the answer... sorry was getting copy and paste happy with JSNooBs existing code lol

Comment: Hmm i get the following error
TypeError: $(...).data(...).add is not a function
My code looks like this now:

$('#carousel ul.slides > li').click(function(){

           $('#info-text > span').text($(this).data('text'));

           console.log(this);

   });

Comment: If you're code looks like this `<script>
$('#carousel ul.slides > li').click(function(){
 $('#info-text > span').text($(this).data('text'));
 console.log(this);
});
</script>` then you shouldn't be getting an error... `.add is not a function` means that you still have .add in there somewhere. Remove it and you should be good.

Comment: ah got it :-) I was getting the error because of some wrong stuff in my custom.js file. I don't like implementing JS by script tag in html-file. The code by Banning works fine. There is only one mistake, the container gets a class called "info-text" and not a id. But I will edit this. So thx a lot!

Comment: Ah sorry I had `#info-text` because it was in your question and I just copied and pasted.. I'll update the answer for ya :)